# Converting to json correct way using php?

Tags: php

I need an o/p like this ["12","13"] when I do the following json operation

I have a 2 varaiables and getting these values as post data

```
$a = $_POST['cas'];
$b = $_POST['casty'];

$final1 = json_encode($a);
$final2= json_encode($b);

$final_value = '['.$final1.','.$final2.']';
```

I am getting output as ["12","13"].I am doing correct way in php ? any other ways to get json object apart from this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array for that like this:

```
$array = array($_POST['cas'], $_POST['casty']);
$final_value = json_encode($array);
```

Note: no need to create `$a` and `$b`.

By adding `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` as a 2nd parmeter you'll get `key => value` data like a normal php array. JSON Arrays don't have keys, therefore most of the time `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` is useful.

```
JSON Array ["data", "data2", "data3"] 
JSON Object {0:"data", 1:"data2", 2:"data3"}
```